# common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: Unexpected end of file from server apex

Tags: java, web-services, rest, salesforce, apex

I'm Trying to callout a rest service in apex Salesforce, but it doesn't work well when I call from Salesforce, Already try it with ARC Chrome, and a Java program that I made and works fine.
Give me this error when I put the max Timeout.

> common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: Unexpected end of file from server apex

And when I change it without Timeout give me:

> An unexpected error has occurred: Read timed out

So I really don't know what is happening I use the same logic script to callout another Rest Service and it works fine.

This is my cod till now:

```
@future (callout=true)
    public static void SendNitrosOautIncluded(Decimal cantidadNitros, String id_cuenta) {

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        Http http = new Http();
        try {
            map<String, Endpoint__c> endPoints = Endpoint__c.getall();
            Endpoint__c endPoint = endPoints.get('PtxAddNitros');
            String endPointPtx= (String)endPoint.get('Endpoint__c');
            System.debug(endPointPtx+id_cuenta);
            //req.setTimeout(60000);
            req.setEndpoint(endPointPtx+id_cuenta);
            req.setMethod('POST');
            req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');                  
            JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true); 
            gen.writeStartObject();
            gen.writeNumberField('credits', cantidadNitros);        
            //MANAGE RESPONSE
            String objSended= gen.getAsString();
            System.debug(objSended);
            req.setBody(objSended);            
            res = http.send(req);            
            String resp=res.getBody();            
            System.debug(resp);
            System.debug(res.toString());
            System.debug('STATUS:'+res.getStatus());
            System.debug('STATUS_CODE:'+res.getStatusCode());
           /* Map<String, Object> m =(Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(resp);
            System.debug(m);
            //CONTROL DE ERRORES
            String data=(String)m.get('data');  
            String status=(String)m.get('status');  
            if(status.equals('200')){
                System.debug('CORRECTO');
            }*/




        } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
            facturaDeudor.errorMessage(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The Issue was about the Firewall, Put all de addresses of the URL in the whitelist of the server to callout and it works.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003652&type=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Issue was about the Firewall, Put all de addresses of the URL in the whitelist of the server to callout and it works. 
help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003652&type=1